# Can't ping localhost from utun interface

Tags: networking, ping, osx-el-capitan

I have opened a utun interface and used the following commands to set it up.

```
sudo ifconfig utun0 10.0.3.1 10.0.3.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
sudo route add -net 10.0.3.0 10.0.3.1
sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

Executing ifconfig lo0, en0, and utun0 results in:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>

en0: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=10b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV>
    ether 95:ab:3d:5c:07:29 
    inet 192.168.0.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex,flow-control>)
    status: active 

utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.3.1 --> 10.0.3.1 netmask 0xffffff00
```

Executing netstat -nr results in:

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGSc           35     1195     en0
10.0.3/24          10.0.3.1           UGSc            0        0   utun0
10.0.3.1           10.0.3.1           UH              2        0   utun0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             47    45013     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
192.168.0          link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.0.1/32     link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.0.1        48:54:70:de:60:09  UHLWIir        36      804     en0   1058
192.168.0.101/32   link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.0.101      95:ab:3d:5c:07:29  UHLWI           0       82     lo0
192.168.0.103      8e:76:28:93:35:f5  UHLWIi          1      325     en0   1180
224.0.0            link#4             UmCS            1        0     en0
224.0.0.251        a9:d5:8c:80:48:17  UHmLWI          0        0     en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#4             UCS             0        0     en0

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
::1                                     ::1                             UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI            lo0
ff01::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
```

Now I can create a ping request packet with source IP: 10.0.3.1 and destination IP: 192.168.0.101 and get a successful reply. But if I change the destination IP to 127.0.0.1 I get no reply.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this by adding a pf redirect rule:

```
rdr on utun0 from any to 10.0.3.5 -> lo0
```

And then pinging 10.0.3.5 from the utun interface. I still don't know why I can't directly ping the localhost while I can ping the en0 interface without problems.